# How to make variables accessable to other scripts but not overriden in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference

I have a prefab of a tower which has public variables for some basic stats like damage and range. These stats are overiden by what is in the inspector even if the values are at 0 but it will show the number defined in code.

For example if I have it set to 0 on the prefab and 5 on the Start function in code, it will show up as 5 when it is instantiated however it will do only 0 damage. And it will do only the amount of damage defined in the prefab even if I am attempting to overwrite this in code.

I tried making the variables private but then I cant reference the values for the enemy which I am doing like so

```
Tower_1 t1Dmg = t1Ref.GetComponent<Tower_1>();
Tower_2 t2Dmg = t2Ref.GetComponent<Tower_2>();
Tower_3 t3Dmg = t3Ref.GetComponent<Tower_3>();


if(other.transform.tag == "Bullet") 
{
    Debug.Log("tower1Hitme");
    health -= t1Dmg.t1Damage; // Minus tower 1's current damage from our health per collision with "Bullet"
}

if (other.transform.tag == "Rocket")
{
    health -= t2Dmg.rocketDamage; // Minus tower 2's current damage from our health per collision with "Rocket"
}

if (other.transform.tag == "Rocket")
{
    health -= t2Dmg.miniRocketDamage; // Minus tower 1's current damage from our health per collision with "MiniRocket"
}
```

Its probably something very basic I'm missing but I can't seem to have the values correspond to what has been set in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [HideInInspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html):

Example usage:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    [HideInInspector]
    public int p = 5;
}
```

Comment: I see, I guess I should have realized if its hidden in the inspector it cant override it. I have been using that for some other variables too.